# In Swift, how to flip a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView that when a cell is pressed I need it to flip to another cell. For example from this:

[image]

To this:[image]

One cell at a time. I saw a post on how to do it in objective-c here:
[How can I flip an iOS UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688083/how-can-i-flip-an-ios-uitableviewcell)

Is there a way to do it in Swift?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the link you provided suggested in swift? The Obj-C code in that link is nearly identical in swift. Try following those steps and auto-complete in Xcode should do most of the work for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here in case you need the disclosure indicators. You will have to use a custom one in order to flip it as far as I know. I found this function that will flip a cell's view horizontally, but I don't believe that is what you want.

```
cell.contentView.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1))
```

I would just make both cells with the custom disclosure indicators that you just save copies of the disclosure indicator images flipped, and then when you click the cell make them swap like so:

```
var isFirstCell = true
var indexOfSwappingCell: Int = 0

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    isFirstCell = !isFirstCell
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: indexOfSwappingCell, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == indexOfSwappingCell {
        if isFirstCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell1
            //setup cell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell2
            //setup cell
            return cell
        }
    } else {
        //setup other cells

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

In case you want the code that guys used, I just ran through it into [objectivec2swift](https://objectivec2swift.com/)

```
//flip the view to flipView

@IBAction func flipButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.transitionWithView(self.contentView, duration: 0.6, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.contentView.insertSubview(flipView, aboveSubview: normalView)
    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
    })
}
//flip the view back to normalView

@IBAction func flipBackButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.transitionWithView(self.contentView, duration: 0.6, options: .TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.contentView.insertSubview(normalView, aboveSubview: flipView)
    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
    })
}
```

To respond to your comment

add these 2 above `viewDidLoad`

```
var isFirstLoad = true
var contentViewToFlip: UIView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == indexOfSwappingCell {

        if isFirstCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell1
            if isFirstLoad == false {
                UIView.transitionWithView(self.contentView, duration: 0.6, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {() -> Void in
                    contentViewToFlip.insertSubview(cell.contentView, aboveSubview: contentViewToFlip)
                    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
                })
            }
            isFirstLoad = false
            contentViewToFlip = cell.contentView
            //setup cell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell2
            UIView.transitionWithView(self.contentView, duration: 0.6, options: .TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {() -> Void in
                contentViewToFlip.insertSubview(cell.contentView, aboveSubview: contentViewToFlip)
                }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            })
            contentViewToFlip = cell.contentView
            //setup cell
            return cell
        }
    } else {
        //setup other cells

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out.  That link is great too!

Comment: quick question, for the 'cell.contentView.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1))' is that declared in the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Yes, but it will flip everything as if you put it up to a mirror.

Comment: and if you like the answer, give it a check and upvote ;)

Comment: oh, I just want it to flip to the next cell. Like if you press a coupon there will be a flip animation to the redeem coupon cell

Comment: I haven't tested it, but you could try what I just did in the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I tried the last section of code, I keep getting an error, 'ViewController has no member contentView'

Comment: my bad, I messed up... just fixed that problem, but it still might not work. Honestly, it would be much better to do this through a delegate protocol with the cell, but I was trying to keep it simple. I'll write one when i get off work if you still need help.

Comment: That's ok you don't have to do that. Thanks for your help